# How to augment Node.js classes?

Tags: typescript

I need to add functionality to existing Node.js class, specifically `Server`. Is it possible to use something along the lines of the following snippet?

```
import * as net from 'net'

type ShutdownableServer = net.Server & { shutdown(): Promise<void> }

function withShutdown(server: net.Server): ShutdownableServer {
  /* ... */
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to use something along the lines of the following snippet?

Yes.

```
type ShutdownableServer = net.Server & { shutdown(): Promise<void> }

function withShutdown(server: net.Server): ShutdownableServer {
  const result = server as ShutdownableServer; 
  result.shutdown = /*your code*/;
  return result;
}
```

## More

I used an assertion. Docs https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/type-assertion.html